# Há como compactar dados armazenados em byte[]?

Tags: c#, postgresql

Recebo um `byte[]` que é uma imagem, e salvo no banco (Postgres) em uma coluna o `byte[]` todo. Tem como eu compactar? Deixar menor esse `byte[]`?

Comment: pergunta: porque iria querer compactar?

Comment: para não pesar tanto no banco

Comment: A solução para isso, seria guardar o caminho físico da imagem então em vez de salvar ela no banco

Comment: não posso guardar em caminho fisico, a principio é no banco mesmo

Comment: Em tempo de execução na aplicação, é possível criar um Buffer, mas no banco creio não ser possível

Comment: Se a mensagem em questão for um Bitmap (.BMP), a compactação pode produzir uma boa redução no número de bytes do seu byte[]. Já se for .JPG, .PNG ou .GIF (formatos que já comprimem a imagem), essa redução pode não ser significativa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tente algo como o código a seguir: (Faça seus testes e certifique-se que está tudo correto.)

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    // Fonte: http://stackoverflow.com/a/271264/194717
    using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        zipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        zipStream.Close();
        return compressedStream.ToArray();
    }
}

public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] bSource)
{
    // Fonte: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350776/help-with-programmatic-compression-decompression-to-memorystream-with-gzipstream
    using (var inStream = new MemoryStream(bSource))
    using (var gzip = new GZipStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        gzip.CopyTo(outStream);
        return outStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```